# Castle.Windsor Register AllTypes With An Interceptor

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, registration, iinterceptor

Why does the following not intercept calls to IBusinessService with the LogAspect?

```
container.Register(AllTypes.Of<IBusinessService>()
    .FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .ConfigureFor<BusinessService>(
        c => c.Named(typeof(BusinessService).Name)
            .Interceptors(InterceptorReference.ForType<LogAspect>()).Anywhere));
```

If I register each implementation of IBusinessService using the Component.For syntax then it works.

Comment: Do you mean to register this as Component.For<IBusinessService>().ImplementedBy<BusinessService>() or Component.For<BusinessService>() ?

Comment: Like Component.For<IBusinessService>().ImplementedBy<BusinessService>(), but there are multiple implementations of BusinessService. I ended up registering each on on it's own.